What's the difference between Body.setAngularVelocity and Body.setAngularSpeed
Usually the term velocity includes a direction and a magnitude component, but setAngularVelocity only takes a scalar value. I see setAngularVelocity also sets angularSpeed, but as an absolute value, so maybe angularSpeed is the direction portion? And angularVelocity is the magnitude/how fast(speed?!)? Is velocity a vector in that the sign is the direction and the absolute value is the magnitude/speed?
https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/src/body/Body.js#L598
Body.setAngularVelocity = function(body, velocity) {
        var timeScale = body.deltaTime / Body._baseDelta;
        body.anglePrev = body.angle - velocity * timeScale;
        body.angularVelocity = (body.angle - body.anglePrev) / timeScale;
        body.angularSpeed = Math.abs(body.angularVelocity);
    };

